# Check for null after FirstOrDefault?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to find the first member of a dictionary which satisfies certain condition and then get some properties from the found item. My concern is what if no item is found. Consider this code:

```
Dictionary<int, Class1> dict;
....
....
var foundPair = dict.Select(i => new { i }).FirstOrDefault(somePredicate);
SomeClass result = null;
if (foundPair != null)
    result = foundPair.i.Value.SomeProp;
```

The `result` is what I'm looking for and this code looks obscure to me. Can we get the above functionality in a single linq chain? I mean something similar to this:

```
var result = protsDict.Select(i => new { i }).FirstOrDefault(somePredicate).SomeLinqChain(...).i.Value.SomeProps;
```

And the result should be `SomeProps` if an item is found and `null` if no item is found.

Comment: You're looking for `.?`.

Comment: You should use *Where*

Comment: Could this be usefull? var result = someExpression.FirstOrDefault() ?? ADefaultValueOrDefaultInstance;

Comment: `var result = dict.Where(somePredicate).Select(x => x.i.Value.SomeProp).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be rewritten, in various ways, as:

The key is: use `Where`

```
var result = protsDict.Where(somePredicate).SomeLinqChain(...) //some chain
            .Where(someMore) //some more
            .Where(i => i.Value != null) //or even...
            .Select(i =>i.Value.SomeProps).FirstOrDefault();//then select; take or skip
```

Comment: Why would you use `Where`? The whole point of the overload to `FirstOrDefault` is to pass a predicate.

Comment: Starting with `Where` will give you the option to `Select`. Read the duplicate and you'll see a typical scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Where` followed by `Take(1)` to isolate at most one element which satisfies the condition.

```
var foundPair = dict
    .Select(i => new { i })
    .Where(somePredicate)
    .Take(1)
    .Select(x => some_mapping(x)
    ...;
```

When done this way, the subsequent expressions will only be executed if the first element satisfying the predicate has been found, and only on that element. Should more elements satisfy the predicate, all but the first one would be ignored.

In that sense, this technique works the same as `FirstOrDefault`, only in a safe way.